# Load balancer for kubernetes clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I need some help configuring my load balancer for my Kubernetes clusters. The internal load balancer works fine. Now, I'd like to expose the service via https and I'm stumped on the Ingress configuration.

Comment: Syed, if you could edit your post to include some (redacted) code that you're working with so far, that would help us get you where you need to go. Are you getting error messages? If so, that would be helpful to include. I have a working config that I'd be happy to share but I'd like to know what you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please take in count that whenever any HTTP(S) load balancer is configured through Ingress, you must not manually change or update the configuration of the HTTP(S) load balancer. That is, you must not edit any of the load balancer's components, including target proxies, URL maps, and backend services. Any changes that you make are overwritten by GKE.

So, once that we are aware about the above, We have to know that Ingress for Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancing deploys the Google Cloud Internal HTTP(S) Load Balancer. This private pool of load balancers is deployed in your network and provides internal load balancing for clients and backends within your VPC. As per [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#ingress_for_external_and_internal_traffic) documentation.

Now, we are ready to configure an [Ingress for Internal Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/internal-load-balance-ingress), This is an example about how to configure a simple Ingress in order to expose a simple service.

My suggestion is to try first to implement the first configuration in order to know how an ingress works, and then, try to configure an ingress for GKE as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress) documentation.

Let me know if you still having doubts about it or if you need more assistance.

Have a nice day, and stay safe.